# Is VestaCP compatible with Centos 7

Tags: centos, webserver, digital-ocean

I want to install VestaCP on my digitalocean droplet. I can't see supported os list on vestacp's web site. Is VestaCP compatible with centos 7 ?

http://vestacp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its CentOS 7 compatible, you only have to use their installer running this:

curl -O http://vestacp.com/pub/vst-install.sh

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it. I just tried installing it on a minimal-install image of CentOS 7, and it failed. Tried to find /sbin/ifconfig (7 minimal-install uses nmcli and nmtui) and failed.

The rhel-specific install script that got downloaded only has provisions for CentOS 5 and 6 in it, no mention of 7, and so the install failed further on when adding some rpm repos.

tldr: doesn't look like it has support for it yet.